# Office 365 powershell, how to get credentials object with MFA

Tags: powershell, office-365

My goal is to extract the recent messages from the message center and push it to another list that is accessible to non-admins too. I found this script in a forum, exports a csv, that is already a progress. It works in my test tenant, but not in production, because there we use multi-factor authentication.

```
$target = "C:\temp\messages.csv"
#Connect-MsolService 
$cred = Get-Credential
$jsonPayload = (@{userName=$cred.username;password=$cred.GetNetworkCredential().password;} | convertto-json).tostring()
$cookie = (invoke-restmethod -contenttype "application/json" -method Post -uri "https://api.admin.microsoftonline.com/shdtenantcommunications.svc/Register" -body $jsonPayload).RegistrationCookie
$jsonPayload = (@{lastCookie=$cookie;locale="en-US";preferredEventTypes=@(2)} | convertto-json).tostring()
$events = (invoke-restmethod -contenttype "application/json" -method Post -uri "https://api.admin.microsoftonline.com/shdtenantcommunications.svc/GetEvents" -body $jsonPayload)
$events.Events | export-csv -LiteralPath $target -NoTypeInformation
```

As far as I understood, I need to use the Connect-MsolService command to connect with MFA, but I didn't find any reference for getting the credentials out from this session to be used in the code later. Can somebody help me with this?